# How to display the second word first with dot

Tags: angularjs

I have an issue to display the name in the web site.

we get the clientUserName(first and last name) in a single string.

Now I want to display the first and last name first char with a dot.

if the clientUserName is Srirama Reddy
I need to display Sriram R.

also, accept first name up to 12 Characters

how can I do this in angular

my Controller code

```
    this.loadCurrentClientUserDetails = function () {
    var clientUserdetails = Common.GetCurrentClient();
    self.clientUserName = clientUserdetails.UserName;
    self.clientName = clientUserdetails.ClientName;

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can use this

```
  var data=self.clientUserName.split(' ');
  var FinalName=data[0].substring(0,12)+" "+data[1].substring(0,1)+"."
```

this will provide you your required data(also, accept first name up to 12 Characters).

Answer (score 1):

```
var parts = self.clientUserName.split(' ');
var shortedClientName = parts[0] + ' ' + parts[1][0] + '.';
console.log(shortedClientName); //Sriram R.
```